# What is the correct or preferred nomenclatural vernacular for physical examinations?

Tags: terminology, physical-health

I was using a running log app and came across terminology commonly used to describe a "**physical**" — as in a type of medical provider visit that is scheduled once a year and typically requires a lengthy lead-time to secure. In my mind, this term overlaps with its literal counterpart: a "**physical examination**" - as in an examination of the physical nature (as opposed to instrumental/laboratory/etc.).

While trying to use both concepts in the same sentence, I was at a loss regarding how to go about doing so.  Do I refer to it as a "physical examination (non-physical)"?  I thought that could't be right, and so I hopped on here to ask what the proper vernacular is in the clinical setting.

How do you designate or denote a "physical" and a "physical examination" as to be able to differentiate or address them with specificity?

Comment: I think the only way to distinguish intent is context. (In the US)

Comment: I've not seen tests referred to as physical exams/examinations (I'm a physician in the US.) To me, a *physical exam* is a "hands on" examination. You are physically examining the patient; you can't do it remotely. Pretty much everything else is called a test or a procedure: blood tests/lab tests, stress test, EMG, etc. Procedures include catheterizations, colonoscopies, etc. Not all procedures are invasive.